# How to create virtual key presses?

Tags: python, workflow

In sculpt mode, I want to switch between tools and change size/falloff using a MIDI controller (pen in the right hand, left hand on the controller). A possible solution would be a python script that: 1. reads MIDI input (using e.g. **rtmidi**), 2. generates virtual key presses ('f', 'F', 'm', etc.). I'm using Arch Linux.

It's quite easy to read the MIDI input. For the key press generation I tried three different python packages - all having some kind of issue:

1. **pynput**: Key presses are generated and appear in Terminal/Emacs/Browser correctly. However in Blender, only the first virtual key press appears while the following are somehow swallowed (sporadically every 1/20 event arrives).
2. **keyboard**: Needs roots privileges. Would be ok, but didn't work out of the box.
3. **pyautogui**: Key presses are generated and all arrive in Blender. 'f' and 'F' however just cause a short flicker as if 'f' followed by return are generated (which cannot be observed when sent to a terminal).

For testing purposes I wrote a small script that generates an 'f' key press:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write('f')
# alternatively
# pyautogui.press('f')
# or (didn't work)
# pyautogui.keyDown('f')
# pyautogui.keyUp('f')

# from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
# keyboard = Controller()
# keyboard.press('f')
# keyboard.release('f')
# alternatively
# keyboard.type('f')
```

Has anybody a clue why events are swallowed in the case of **pynput** or why 'f'/'F' are directly commited in the case of **pyautogui**?

Are there other possibilities to control blender externally or internally (e.g. a MIDI addon - **AddRoutes** doesn't seem to fit the requirements)?

Any help would be highly appreciated!